# Insertion failure on table , make a new entry on foreign table also

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp

I am using postgres database with hibernate as an ORM. 
I have a table named district with foreign key division.

But after insertion, it makes new entry both on division and district table. At first, it makes a new entry on division table (new id is created at that time). Then it makes new entry on district table with the new id of division.

```
CREATE TABLE district(   
  id SERIAL,    
  division_id INTEGER REFERENCES division(id),   
  name varchar(30),   
  PRIMARY KEY (id) 
);
```

**This is my model:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "district")
public class District implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="division_id")
    private Division division;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    // getter setter
```

**My controller:**

```
@GetMapping(value = "/createdistrict")
public ModelAndView  createdistrict(Locale locale, Model model) {

    List<Division> allDivisionList = new ArrayList<Division>();
    allDivisionList = this.districtService.listdivisions() ;
    Map<Integer,String> allDivision = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,String>();
    for( int i=0 ; i < allDivisionList.size() ; i++) {

        allDivision.put(allDivisionList.get(i).getId() , allDivisionList.get(i).getName());
    }

    return new ModelAndView("createdistrict" , "allDivision" , allDivision);
}
```

**DAO:**

```
@Override
public void adddistrict(District p) {
   Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
   session.saveOrUpdate(p);
   logger.info("District saved successfully, Phone Details=" + p);
}
```

**my jsp page:**

```
 <tr>
                    <td>
                        Division 
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <select id="division" name="division">
                          <c:forEach items="${allDivision}" var="allDivision">
                          <option value="${allDivision.key}">${allDivision.value }</option>
                          </c:forEach>
                    </select> 
                    </td> 
                  </tr>
```

[image: create district page]

Comment: Please provide the `Division` model and the code in the controller or service from where you are passing the `District` to the dao.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you couldn't set `Division` object to your `District` object which is a sub-table. Find object of super class using the `id` of the selected `Division`. Then set object to `District` object. After then, save your sub table object which is named as `District`.

Done.